# Anyone using javascript mvc?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Can anyone give me the feed back on their experiences with Javascript MVC? I have used Asp.net MVC 2 in the past and did not realize there were a MVC framework on the client.

I have used Knockout js in the past, is it similar to javascript mvc?

Would my code be easier to maintain and develop if I use MVC on the client?

JD

Comment: If you already wrote a lot of javascript and sometimes don't know where to put or to maintain all the stuff, JavaScript MVC will open your eyes! It solves a lot of problems.

Answer (score 2):

**Check out [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org).** It helps you with app structure, strict separation of view / logic, testing...

I believe [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) in general can help you a lot, especially when you have to maintain bigger project. TDD is easy with AngularJS, as there is full testing environment included.

Answer (score 1):

It makes it easier to build alternative clients (mobile) to your server app if the server app is just a point to get data.  That way you can support mobile devices as well as traditional browsers.  Another advantage is you offload the work of rendering to the client, so the server doesn't speed as much time generating and sending markup to the client.

If you have a lot of legacy code and have no plans for mobile devices it could be a hard sell to rearchitect an existing system.  Client MVC is definitely the future.

Comment: Hi Justin, you mentioned offloading the work of rendering to the client. Can you explain more? Is it possible to have more of the application logic on the client (i.e. the rules about moving to different screens) rather than going back to the server as traditional web MVC is done on the server?

Comment: What about Knockout? It has clever bindings that follow the MVVM way of working but there seems to be a lot more that JSMVC does, am I right to assume that?

Answer (score 1):

also check out https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc which compares a lot of MVC farmeworks, by building the same TODO application in every one of them.